# python regex to match lines not with quotes

Tags: python, regex

I have a regex which is used to match the text, but i need to match the text leaving the text within quotes.

Consider:

```
I have a pen1
I have a pen1 "green"
```

In fact i need to leave the text within quotes and say that both the lines are same.The below code will match the same line and then increment with the no.s to reduce the redundancy among the data in text.But i need to take the text leaving the text within the "" and take the remaining text,if the remaining text are found to be same then increment the no.s

code:thnks to @falsetru

```
import re
numbers = {}
with open('1.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        row = re.split(r'(\d+)', line.strip())
        words = tuple(row[::2])  # Extract non-number parts to use it as key
        if words not in numbers:
            numbers[words] = [int(n) for n in row[1::2]]  # extract number parts.
        numbers[words] = [n+1 for n in numbers[words]]  # Increase numbers.
        row[1::2] = map(str, numbers[words])  # Assign back numbers
        print(''.join(row))
```

What to include to not consider the text within the " "?

Please help,Answers will be appreciated!

Comment: Your regex splits on numbers - what does that have to do with the problem at hand?

Answer (score 2):

You can do that without regular expressions:

```
>>> s = 'foo "bar" baz'
>>> ''.join(s.split('"')[::2])
'foo  baz'
```

Basically, it split the string at `"` characters, keeps even-indexed parts, and joins them.

If you really want to use a regexp:

```
>>> s = 'foo "bar" baz'
>>> re.sub('".*"', '', s)
'foo  baz'
```